# How to read .sql/.txt file with oracle pl sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, plsql

Please can you tell me how can i read/parse an sql or text file with pl sql !
the objectif is that i have a file containing key words and all i want is procedure with pl sql that can read that file and at the moment where the keyword is found it execute a specific function.

Ps: i don't think that "DBMS_SQL.PARSE" is the solution for this situation !

Thank u :)

Comment: PL/SQL runs in the database, so the first issue could be that the file would need to be on the database server or a shared drive accessible to it, and not on your desktop PC (unless Oracle is running on your desktop PC).

Comment: What is the file format you need to parse? What kind of keywords? Can you include an example and show what you want to extract from it?

Comment: If you don't want to insert data (with the SQLLoader suggestion), but want to initiate some kind of operation, you may need to use a "client side" language like Java or Python to read the file.  Then you can call the database functions.  Check out Oracle's Python driver 'python-oracledb' https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/.  The documentation shows how to call PL/SQL functions and procedures: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, some of which are the following:

- if you create an **external table** (based on that file), you'll be able to access it from both SQL and PL/SQL, as if it were an *ordinary* table
- or, you can write a PL/SQL procedure and utilize the **`UTL_FILE`** built-in package to read file's contents

Both options require you to have access to a **directory**, an Oracle object created and owned by a privileged user, SYS, which will grant you (at least) `read` privileges on it (the directory). That directory points to a filesystem directory (folder) which contains the file; it is usually located on the database server. That's kind of a *drawback* if you aren't a DBA (so you can't do it yourself) and there's no DBA who will do it for you.

---

Yet another option - which lets you store the file **locally**, on your own PC - is the command prompt utility named **SQL Loader**. You'd write a so-called *control file* which instructs Oracle where and how to store file data (into a table in your schema). SQL*Loader is installed along with any Oracle database; if you don't have any on your PC, check the Client software.

Once you load data into the table, you can do whatever you want with it.